# Editing npm packages in a webapp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have a web app in which I installed an npm package. Now I noted that I need to add code to customize it. I tried to go to node_modules, found the package, and edited it but the changes don't show. is there a way to do it? 
Also to avoid losing the changes I make to the packages I forked the package from GitHub.

----Update
I have aa package called react-image-crop the relative path is `node_modules/react-image-crop`.
Every time the below function gets called I want to log X and Y of the position:

```
  let pageX;
  let pageY;

  if (e.touches) {
    pageX = e.touches[0].pageX;
    pageY = e.touches[0].pageY;
  } else {
    pageX = e.pageX;
    pageY = e.pageY;
  }

  return {
    x: pageX,
    y: pageY,
  };
}
```

I tried to add `console.log(pageX, pageY)` but I don't get the respected output. 
the package I'm working on is https://github.com/DominicTobias/react-image-crop (hope I can have links to packages in my question otherwise I can delete it)

Comment: Add a [mcve] for better understanding your question.

Comment: I've added the actual package I'm working on. Please let me know if you need other information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to modify npm package check this checklist:

- check that you modify compiled/builded files (not a source)
- check which exactly build you are modifying (packages may has multiple builds)
- after you done and need some fix create issue in package tracker (or pr)
- for constant fix for project (if long discussion or maintaining) use [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package)